# Error while running codeunit through job queue on Navision

Tags: rdlc, development-environment, job-scheduling, navision, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I have an Error while running a Codeunit through job queue, even though this code unit works fine when I run it manually.
Error:
"Microsoft Dynamics NAV Server attempted to issue a client callback to create a .NET object: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection (Report 50126 NewOrdersCust). Client recalls are not supported for Microsoft Dynamics NAV Server."

This code unit runs a report and saves it as a pdf file in a folder.

### CodeUnit:

```
OnRun(VAR Rec : Record "Job Queue Entry")
 IF GUIALLOWED THEN BEGIN
 programm:='\\MB\Navision\ReportsMB\PDFSoftware\cpdf.exe';
//Merged PDF1
Output := '\\MB\Navision\ReportsMB\Customers.pdf';
directory:= '\\MB\Navision\ReportsMB\2019\Customers';
Filename1:='\\MB\Navision\ReportsMB\2019\Kunden_Vertrieb\CustomersOrders.pdf';
Report1.SAVEASPDF(Filename1);
END;
```

The report is actually based on an SQL query:

### Report:

```
MyReport - OnPreDataItem()
Servername:='*.*.*.*';
DBName:='DB';
GetSQLConnection(SQLConnection,Servername,DBName);

QueryinText:='select * from [SickDays] K  Order by Year DESC, Code ASC, Monat DESC ';

SQLCommand:=SQLCommand.SqlCommand(QueryinText,SQLConnection);
SQLConnection.Open();
Queryread :=SQLCommand.ExecuteReader;

MyReport - OnAfterGetRecord()
IF (Queryread.Read()) THEN
       BEGIN
       LoopCount+=1;
       Year:= Queryread.Item(0);
       KrankDays:=Queryread.Item(5);
       END
ELSE
    BEGIN
       SQLConnection.Close();
       CurrReport.BREAK;
    END;

SETRANGE(Number,1,  LoopCount);

MyReport - OnPostDataItem()

GetSQLConnection(VAR SQLConnection : DotNet "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection";Servername : Code[20];DBName : Code[20])
SQLConnection :=
  SQLConnection.SqlConnection(
    STRSUBSTNO(
      'Data Source=%1;Initial Catalog=%2;Integrated Security=SSPI',
      Servername,DBName));
```

### [This report contains the following .net variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EySew.png)

Answer (score 0):

On the .net variables you have probably set property `RunOnClient` to True. You can’t do that if you want to run this report on server. Set this property to false and make sure you have needed libraries on the nav server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. All the .net variables property RunOnClient are set to true. How could I check if I have the needed libraries on the nav server, please?

Comment: How do you know you have those libraries on the client?

Comment: You can use linked objects instead btw https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/using-linked-objects